# Undefined index page if get page

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

I cant find specific answer for my problem. So what I'm trying to do is to define index page by using only index.php. This is my code so far:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){

        if(!$_GET['page']){
            include "template/home.php";
        }

        if($_GET['page']=="gallery"){
            include "template/gallery.php";
        }
    }
?>
```

When I'm trying to open it on local host there is nothing only white screen without any errors. Only thing that makes me problem is this string, but still without any errors, can't find what problem is...

```
if(!$_GET['page']){
    include "template/home.php";
}
```

I was trying to find on internet solution, but there was nothing helpful, hope u can help me :)

Comment: Are you checking your error logs? Is it set to log? Does the `template/home.php` load?

Comment: @chris85 it's not loading that's the problem, there is only white screen on browser, I have no problem with other ?page=something pages only with a index page... I'm trying to define index page, when u go to www.sometging.com to open specific index page like some specific file that I've put in index.php example: home.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're contradicting yourself in your code. Your example reads like this: "If page is set, proceed. Then, if page is not set, include the home page, if page is gallery, then include the gallery page." Do you see the issue? The `isset()` check will ensure that the code with the negation operator `!` is not run.

The solution is to move that code outside of the primary `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['page'])){

             if($_GET['page']=="gallery"){
                include "template/gallery.php";
               }  
            }
           else{
            include "template/home.php";         
            }
        ?>
```